# AS3 ArgumentError: Error #1063: Expected 2, got 0

Tags: flash, actionscript, argument-error

I keep getting this error: ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on code::SimonPad(). Expected 2, got 0.
I have no idea what's going on, especially with uint. Any helps will be much appreciated.
I have displayed two code blocks below. They are based on Actionscript 3.0
When I tried to run these codes, I didn't get any on the stage. This codes are supposed to display four different colored boxes, but it didn't work at all. Help, please.

```
package code
```

{

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;


public class Main extends MovieClip
{


    private var pads:Array = new Array();

    public function Main()
    {
        var pad:SimonPad;

        pad = new SimonPad(0xAA0000, 0xFF0000);
        pad.x = 5;
        pad.y = 5;
        addChild(pad)
        pads.push(pad)

        pad = new SimonPad(0x0000AA, 0x6666FF);
        pad.x = 205;
        pad.y = 205;
        addChild(pad)
        pads.push(pad)

        pad = new SimonPad(0xAAAA00, 0xFFFF00);
        pad.x = 5;
        pad.y = 205;
        addChild(pad)
        pads.push(pad)

        pad = new SimonPad(0x00AA00, 0x00FF00);
        pad.x = 205;
        pad.y = 205;
        addChild(pad)
        pads.push(pad)

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, theFrame);
    }

    private function theFrame(e:Event):void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < pads.length; i++) 
        {
            (pads[i] as SimonPad).update();
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
package code
```

{

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class SimonPad extends Sprite
{


    private var dark:Shape;
    private var light:Shape;

    public function SimonPad(darkColor:uint, lightColor:uint)
    {
        dark = new Shape();
        dark.graphics.beginFill(darkColor, 1);
        dark.graphics.drawRect(0,0,190,190);
        dark.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(dark);

        light = new Shape();
        light.graphics.beginFill(lightColor, 1);
        light.graphics.drawRect(0,0,190,190);
        light.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(light);

        light.alpha = 0;

        mouseChildren = false;

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, downClicked);
    }

    private function downClicked (e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        flash();
    }

    public function flash():void
    {
        light.alpha = 2;
    }

    public function update():void
    {
        if (light.alpha > 0)
        {
            light.alpha *= 0.85;

            if (light.alpha < 0.0125)
            {
                light.alpha = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The error is saying that you're calling the SimonPad constructor without passing in the 2 required color arguments. However, that is not happening the code that you've shown. This must be occuring somewhere else in your app. If you use the debug Flash Player, the error message will include the line/frame numbers of where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Maybe you instantiate SimonPad "by hands", by putting object from library into scene/frame. Add default values for constructor parameters: SimonPad(darkColor:uint=0, lightColor:uint=0) Trace values from constructor to find all instantiated objects.

Comment: I did debug Flash Player, but there is no error message that will include the line/frame numbers. - Sunil

Comment: I did try to put in the default values, but I only got a black square instead of two. - Smolniy

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you really have a manually placed `SimonPad` instance on your stage at design time. Do track your Flash project for manually placed `SimonPad` instances. Also, in order to get the frame, you can try this trick: In `SimonPad()` function, along with providing default values for constructor arguments, you add the following lines:

```
var e:Error=new Error();
trace(e.getStackTrace());
```

This will net you a trace containing something in line of `at MainTimeline.frameXXX` which has a frame number, or `at Sprite.constructChildren() at Sprite() at SomeClass()` which gives you a hint on which class's library prototype has a `SimonPad` reference.